# Javascript crashes Chrome Browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've got a strange problem.
The following page is a custom form based on Google Forms (from: https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/).
I've also added the code to create a custom "Thank you"-page and this is the part where I think something is going wrong.

Sometimes (and not always) after I submit the form, Chrome crashes completely (the proces chrome.exe is gone in taskmanager).

I used Sawbuck to view the log, but saw no fatal errors.

My chrome browser version: 73.0.3683.75
In the console I don't see any errors.
I tried a few times in Internet Explorer but it didn't crash until now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Template</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/pagination/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
              window.onload=function(){
                $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: 2,
                // the current page that show on start
                startPage: 1,

                // maximum visible pages
                visiblePages: 2,

                initiateStartPageClick: true,

                // template for pagination links
                href: false,

                // variable name in href template for page number
                hrefVariable: '{{number}}',

                // Text labels
                first: 'First',
                prev: 'Prev',
                next: 'Next',
                last: 'Last',

                // carousel-style pagination
                loop: false,

                // callback function
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                  $('.page-active').removeClass('page-active');
                  $('#page'+page).addClass('page-active');
                },

                // pagination Classes
                paginationClass: 'pagination',
                nextClass: 'next',
                prevClass: 'prev',
                lastClass: 'last',
                firstClass: 'first',
                pageClass: 'page',
                activeClass: 'active',
                disabledClass: 'disabled'
                });
            }
</script>

<style>
.answer {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0px;
}

label {
    color: #4ca950;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4ca950;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}

.page-active {
  display: block;
}
.pagination li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px 1px;
}
.pagination li a {
    border: 1px solid #4ca950;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination li:hover {
    background-color: #4ca950;
}
.pagination li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}

.pagination li.next, .pagination li.prev {
    width: auto;
}
.pagination li.active {
    background-color: #4ca950;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #4ca950;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
        body {
        font-size: 18px;
        }
        .pagination li a {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted)  { window.location='thankyou.php'; }"></iframe>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/xxxxx/formResponse" class="form"  target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
        <div class="title col s12"><h1>Form</h1></div>
            <div class="page" id="page1">
                Hi, this is a test.
            </div>

            <div class="page" id="page2">
                <div class="col s12">
                    Yes or no?
                    <div class="answer col s12">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="entry.1276429181" value="Yes" class="with-gap"/><span>Yes</span></label><br>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="entry.1276429181" value="No" class="with-gap"/><span>No</span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12">
                    Input text
                    <div class="answer col s12">
                         <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="entry.47775240" placeholder="Text.."></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>              

                <div class="col s12">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Send
                        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col s12">
                    <ul id="pagination" class="pagination-lg pull-right"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The thankyou.php contains only this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template</title>
</head>

<body>Thank you!</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's difficult to help with all the code and includes just pasted above.  You're really going to have to do some basic debugging to try and identify where the problem is.  Comment all the code out and then add it back, bit by bit until it crashes again.  That should at least point you in the right direction.  It's not easy to crash the browser with Javascript (unless you're trying).  As soon as I see 3rd party includes then I pretty much blame them, but you can't be sure unless you do some investigation yourself.

Comment: The problem is, it only crashes 1 in 30 times or so. I'll try comment out some code. Hopefully someone will recognize this problem in the mean time.

Comment: Do you have some Chrome plugins like ghostry or something, that sound not like a code issue ;)

Comment: I've got no extra extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik script-tags should be placed in the head or body, but yours is inbetween those two. might be just a guess, but this could lead to wrong interpretations by the browser.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've fixed it and I'll try to reproduce the error. But this should normally not produce a complete browser crash.